# CORS configuration with Restify

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I'm seeing that the access-control-allow-origin header is by default being set to a wildcard whenever I do an HTTP GET against my CORS enabled Restify service.  I would rather that it echo the Origin that I send since that is a best practice per [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny).  Any recommendations how I could do that? Tried default headers, formatters, etc. that's in the API docs, but no luck.

Here's what I do:

```
    var server = restify.createServer({
        name: 'People Data Service',
        version: '1.0.6'
    });        
        server.pre(wrapper(restify.pre.pause()));
        // Cleans up sloppy paths
        server.pre(wrapper(restify.pre.sanitizePath()));
        server.use(wrapper(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable)));
        server.use(wrapper(restify.authorizationParser()));
        server.use(wrapper(restify.queryParser()));
        server.use(wrapper(restify.bodyParser()));
        server.use(wrapper(restify.CORS()));
    //    server.use(wrapper(restify.fullResponse()));

        // Needed this for OPTIONS preflight request: https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/284
        function unknownMethodHandler(req, res) {
            if (req.method.toUpperCase() === 'OPTIONS') {
                console.log('Received an options method request from: ' + req.headers.origin);
                var allowHeaders = ['Accept', 'Accept-Version', 'Content-Type', 'Api-Version', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Authorization'];

                if (res.methods.indexOf('OPTIONS') === -1) {
                    res.methods.push('OPTIONS');
                }

                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
                res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', true);
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', allowHeaders.join(', '));
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', res.methods.join(', '));
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
                res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1209600);

                return res.send(204);
            }
            else {
                return res.send(new restify.MethodNotAllowedError());
            }
        }
    server.on('MethodNotAllowed', wrapper(unknownMethodHandler));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by making a simple modification to the cors.js file in Restify as follows:

```
Index: node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/cors.js
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/cors.js    (revision )
+++ node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/cors.js    (revision )
@@ -102,6 +102,7 @@
                                 res.setHeader(AC_ALLOW_ORIGIN, origin);
                                 res.setHeader(AC_ALLOW_CREDS, 'true');
                         } else {
+                            origin = req.headers['origin'];
                                 res.setHeader(AC_ALLOW_ORIGIN, origin);
                         }
```

This will add the origin to the response header even when credentials are set to false.  Also, if you want to whitelist your origins you can simply add this to your configuration:

```
server.use(restify.CORS({'origins': ['http://localhost', 'https://domain.my.com', 'https://anotherDomain.my.com']}));
```

Comment: I think you can just leave the origins attribute empty if you'd like to set it to '*', based on what I see [in the cors plugin file](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/blob/ac88037829d636c4617a50b512919d0cb50fd134/lib/plugins/cors.js#L81): `var origins = opts.origins || ['*'];`

Comment: They recently accepted my pull request so I think this should be in the latest now.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this on my restify base app:

```
    //setup cors
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('accept');
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('sid');
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('lang');
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('origin');
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('withcredentials');
    restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push('x-requested-with');
    server.use(restify.CORS());
```

you need to use restify.CORS.ALLOW_HEADERS.push method to push the header u want into restify first, then using the CORS middleware to boot the CORS function.

Comment: That just allows headers; that will not set the Access-control-allow-origin to echo the origin request header. I've opened a case on Github to see if this could be added. https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/446

Comment: @occasl seems it is set to "*" by default while calling restify.CORS()

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You have to update the source per my answer to get it set the origin.  I submitted a pull request to owner.

Answer (score 0):

It's realy simple.

You need to init a server, befor you can set it up!

var server = restify.createServer( ... );

**To config CORS follow these steps:**

**1. you need to specify ALLOW_HEADERS**

This is array of headers used to set if CORS request is arrived.

**2. configure CORS-Plugin**

server.use(restify.CORS({
    credentials: true
   }));

the option 'credentials' will be used by restif-CORS-plugin to add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials & Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

On the client-side is important to use withCredentials = true on xhr-transport.

i hope these answer will helps you.

... write code & have fun!